# Getting python to write to a file once per hour for 24 hours before creating a new file

Tags: python

Here's the issue I'm having...I can get python to write a file once per hour for 24 hours, no problem. I can get python to write to a new file, again, no problem. But getting python to write to a file for 24 hours and then creating a new file to continue writing to is giving me problems.

The code I'm using to write for 24 is as follows (may be slightly ham-fisted);

```
    import time

    i = 1

    while (i <= 24):            

        time_stamp = time.strftime("%c")

        with open('/home/pi/comp.txt') as file_two:
            contents = file_two.read()
            with open("/home/pi/comp2.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as file_three:
                file_three.writelines(time_stamp + "\n")
                file_three.writelines(contents + "\n" + "\n")

        i += 1
        time.sleep(3600)
```

And the code I'm using to get it to write a new file is;

```
    while (i <= 24):
        file_names = "data_" + str(i) + ".txt"
        with open('/home/pi/comp.txt', 'r') as file_one:
            contents = file_one.readlines()
            with open(file_names, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_four:
                file_four.writelines(contents)
    i += 1
```

As I said, I haven't been able to get them to play nicely with each other. I've tried using a for loop for the second code to get it to use each name individually (e.g. "data_1.txt" for 24 hours, then "data_2.txt" for the next 24), but when I tried that, I got an IsADirectoryError from the compiler. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Your question confuses me. Do you want an hourly log to a file and, when the day changes, have another hourly log with a new file name?

Comment: Yes, I apologize, that's exactly what I'm after.

Comment: That’ll be an os error, so have you checked for accidentally created directories? And you don’t seem to be incrementing i in the second codeblock. Is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You should go with what you tried: using a for loop, to write to `file1.txt` for one day, then moving to `file2.txt`. Except that in your code, you are using the file open modes `w`, `r`, and `a`. These depend on the file existing first. If you want to create a file, use `w+`, `r+`, or `a+`.